# 21st century International Auxiliary Languages

Tags: conlang-creation, history, list-of-languages, auxlangs

What are examples of International Auxiliary Languages (IALs) created and promoted in the 21st century?

I am aware that many people think that Esperanto and Interlingua are in some sense "the last word" on International Auxiliary Languages and that other projects have no realistic chance in succeeding against the established ones. This does not prevent authors to invent new conlangs purposed as IALs, and I like to hear of recent projects fulfilling this criterion.

I am only interested in projects that are worked out to a certain degree, including a grammar, a sketch of derivational morphology, a substantial word list, and some sample texts. Mere conlang stubs don't qualify as answers.

The target group should be really international, conlangs designed for specific subgroups (like interslavic or intergermanic languages) don't count.

Comment: [Lingua Franca Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_Franca_Nova) isn't 21st century, but is pretty close (1998)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only legitimate examples from the Wikipedia article [International auxiliary language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_auxiliary_language) are [Nerrière's Globish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globish_(Nerri%C3%A8re)) (2004) and  [Interslavic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interslavic_language) (2006). Both of these fail OP's criteria, since they are specific to one language branch. Other instances either predate 2000 (Kotava, Lingua Franca Nova), or were not intended as auxlangs (Lojban) or both (Toki Pona). To these, [Wikipedia's list of constructed auxiliary languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_constructed_languages#Auxiliary_languages) adds [Sambahasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sambahsa) (2007) and [Lingwa de planeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingwa_de_planeta) (2010), both of which pass OP's criteria.

Ironically, the Interslavic wikipedia page says that "the language" dates from 1665—but what that actually means is the first Slavic-based auxlang, rather than Interslavic (initially Slovianski-N), which was created by Jan van Steenbergen in 2006.

(The Wikipedia page is also confusing in that it discusses the multiple variants of Slovianski and preceding and subsequent efforts together, rather than highlighting the lineage of the language now labelled Interslavic. But since work is ongoing to unify all those variants, that confusion is not surprising.)

Answer (score 0):

Lojban is an example. It hasn't been created in the 21st century, but it still has a very active community, and its grammar is specified thoroughly. Of course, it has weaknesses for IALs like a distinction between labial and rhotic consonant and a five-vowel system, but it is much less eurocentric than Esperanto and Interlingua.

Comment: It's not intended as an Auxiliary Language though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_auxiliary_language

Comment: According to the article, it is in the IAL sub-category of logical languages (see Classification) and one of Lojban's goals is improved communication between humans of any nationality, which makes it an auxiliary language ("a language meant for communication between people from different nations who do not share a common first language").

Comment: Pierre Janton, who Wikipedia cites in the classification, is an Esperantist who put forward an all-encompassing typology of conlangs, and called it an auxlang typology. Lojban and Loglan were not designed as auxlangs, and the Lojban wiki itself disclaims that purpose: https://mw.lojban.org/papri/Is_Lojban_an_auxlang%3F: "As compared to constructed auxlangs from 1997 til 2016 fluent Lojban speakers have not been promoting Lojban as an auxlang."

Comment: Lojban was of course primarily designed to be a logical language, but as I said, it has some aspects that make it an auxiliary language. To be honest, the article doesn't really answer the question, as a thing not being promoted as some other thing doesn't make it not that other thing. (Homeopathy has been promoted as a medication and Trump has been promoted as a good president.)

Comment: If you're going to ignore the dating requirement, then that makes this question just ask for all auxlangs ever. I don't think this is a valid answer.

Comment: You are right about that. But, as Nick made clear in his answer, languages meeting all the criteria are kind of rare (he found 2 in the dozens of existing ALs). And Lojban's 1997 (Year of publication of "The Complete Lojban Language") is pretty close, although.development started earlier. In Wikipedia's list, it would be the sixth-youngest AL.

Comment: By ‘labial’ did you mean ‘laminal’?

Comment: Yes, actually. Well caught.